# Performance: Ancestor-child type selectors vs. specific element class selectors

Tags: jquery, html, css

When working on a large site, and you need to change all the paragraph text to a different colour for accessibility reasons, is there a significant difference in performance between adding a class to the body and then targeting the elements or should the class be added directly to the elements themselves, e.g.

ADDING CLASS TO BODY RESULTS IN CSS LIKE

```
body.style-two p {
 color: blue;
}
```

ADDING CLASS TO HTML ELEMENT RESULTS IN CSS LIKE

```
p.style-two {
 color: blue;
}
```

I would be using jquery to add the relevant class or classes so I imagine there might also be some performance related issues if you are adding either a single class to the body or multiple classes to the targeted elements.

Optimisation is definitely a concern on much larger sites so I would like to know the 'optimal' way to go about this.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You need to consider overriding and specificity rules. Performance will vary depending on the Browser and doesn't seem to be much of concern in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if performance is the questions, the first way would be the best way to handle this, because you would be adding the class to one element and only one element, imagine you have 1000 "p" tags, traversing the DOM to find all 1000 elements and then add each of them a class VS targeting the body and adding a class to it.

The rest of the processing would be the same, as the browser's engine would have to redraw the elements color in order the user to be able to see it.

Comment: I'm going to agree in this answer for this case specifically. Please elaborate a little more for the op and repaints and redraws. Using JavaScript to change the class of body is easy `document.body.className+=" easy_read ";` compared to iterating of all the p tags